# Ansible: get version of downloaded artifact

Tags: ansible, nexus

I am downloading an artifact with Nexus, using `version:latest` and `keep_name: yes`, is it possible somehow to get the version id in ansible and reuse it later?

Thank you.

Comment: '- name: Get  jar path
  find:
    paths: "{{ jar_path }}/"
    patterns: "*.jar"
  register: jar_file_path'

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Get  jar path
  find:
    paths: "{{ jar_path }}/"
    patterns: "*.jar"
  register: jar_file_path
```